# Angular 2 multi-provider for exporting depencency's dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-services

I'm about to use a [multi-provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Provider-class.html#!#multi) to export the dependencies of my dependency along with itself, so they could be injected into a component at once.

For a component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { FOO_PROVIDERS } from './foo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [FOO_PROVIDERS]
})
export class App {}
```

the [following](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNRalQnnkAPcTItmguW3?p=preview)

```
import {Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

export class Foo {
  constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {}
}

export const FOO_PROVIDERS = [
  provide(Foo, { useClass: Foo, multi: true }),
  provide(Foo, { useValue: HTTP_PROVIDERS, multi: true })
];
```

will result in

> No provider for Http! (App -> Foo -> Http)

And [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/nerxCcdwoju6MBplPXhI?p=preview)

```
import {Inject, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

class Foo {
  constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {}
}

export const FOO_PROVIDERS = [Foo, HTTP_PROVIDERS];
```

will work fine, while I would expect them to do the similar job.

Is there a proper use for multi-provider in this case?

Comment: as a note: one hangup I had- make sure to put FOO_PROVIDERS after defining class FOO, not before

Comment: @Tucker That's correct, classes are not hoisted.

Comment: what is provide here???there is no in angular/core

Comment: @heliyaRahbar It's the definition of a provider. The question addresses Angular 2, provide function was removed in later versions, where provide key is used instead https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#defining-providers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you register `provide(Foo, ...),` than you can

```
constructor(foo:Foo)
```

with `multi: true` you get passed all providers registered as `Foo`

```
constructor(foo:any)
```

With

```
export const FOO_PROVIDERS = [
  provide(Foo, { useClass: Foo, multi: true }),
  provide(Foo, { useValue: HTTP_PROVIDERS, multi: true })
];
```

and

```
constructor(@Inject(Foo) foo:Foo[])
```

you would get passed to `foo` an array containing an instance of `Foo` and a as 2nd item a list of providers (these contained in `HTTP_PROVIDERS`)

**update**

Maybe you have different expectations of what should happen. I don't see how `@Inject(Http) http` is related here. `HTTP_PROVIDERS` is only registered as value for `Foo`. What value you pass to `useValue` is irrelevant when providers are resolved. DI looks up providers for `Foo` and passed the assigned value and doesn't care at all what that value is. There is no provider for `Http` in your example therefore `Foo` itself couldn't get `Http` injected. You would need to register `Http`, which is done when you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` directly to providers (not in `useValue`) because `HTTP_PROVIDERS` contains `Http` (which is equivalent to `provide(Http, {useClass: Http})`

**update2**

```
// An injected service that itself needs to get passed in a dependency
@Injectable()
class Foo {
  constructor(private http:Http);
}

// container for a bunch of dependencies    
@Injectable()
class MyProviders {
  // add everything you want to make available in your components
  constructor(public foo:Foo, public bar:Bar, ...);
}

class MyComponent {
  // inject just MyProviders and use the dependencies it provides
  constructor(private providers: MyProviders) {
    // access provided values
    providers.foo.doSomething();
    providers.bar.doSomethingElse();
  }
}

// Add all providers to allow DI to resolve all above dependencies
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, Foo, Bar]);
```

}

Comment: Sadly, I cannot verify this. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/XyBBUNb6smvq3ieH4fp1?p=preview) and [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/nerxCcdwoju6MBplPXhI?p=preview)  will result in injecting Foo instance (with `constructor(@Inject(Foo) foo)`), the only difference is that Http cannot be resolved in the case of multi-provider. And doing `constructor(foo:Foo[])` would throw 'No provider for Array! (App -> Array)'.

Comment: This works fine in your first Plunker if you add `FOO_PROVIDERS` to `App`s providers instead of `Foo` http://plnkr.co/edit/mxet3Knfirnsf2jA0XGu?p=preview

Comment: In fact, it doesn't, notice `that @Inject(Http) http` was deliberately commented to make sure that injected `foo` is not an array but Foo instance. With uncommented dependency (the [first example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNRalQnnkAPcTItmguW3?p=preview) in the question) the problem is the same as described. So it is still unclear what is wrong with multi-provider use here, and how the answer applies to the situation.

Comment: I updated my answer. It was too long for a comment. Feel free to ask follow up questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so it seems to be impossible to do what I do because multi-provider doesn't expose Http as a separate injectable but keeps it as a part of Foo provider (not sure how to access it through `Foo` then), doesn't it? Could you please add a plunker to demonstrate the first part of the answer? I'm failing to replicate it.

Comment: I think I start to understand your question. I updated my answer again with a proposed solution (doesn't use `multi` - I don't think this leads anywhere). Please add a comment if that goes in the right direction. Still not sure I got what you actually try to accomplish.